# A question related to a complex function satisfying certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

I'm interested in finding all entire functions $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z+1)=g(z)$ and $g(z+i)=e^{2\pi}g(z)$, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

My initial plan was to make use of *Liouville's Theorem* to show that $g$ is constant, but I realized later that the presence of the $e^{2\pi}$ factor might actually mean that this may not be true. Also, the fact that $e^{-2\pi iz}$ is such a non-constant function meant that my strategy
may not work at all. At this point, I'm kind of unsure as to how to proceed, so any help or hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: write $h(z)=g(z)e^{2\pi iz}$and show $h(z+1)=h(z), h(z+i)=h(z)$ hence $h$ is bounded (determined by values on square) so constant

Comment: @Conrad That's a clever strategy. Thanks.

Comment: happy to be of help